# How can I sync a local Eclipse project with a remote server over SFTP/SSH/FTP?

Tags: php, eclipse, ftp, sftp, aptana

I'm looking for a simple way to publish/retrieve PHP code changes from my local copy in Eclipse to a remote server over FTP/SFTP...

I've explored the Remote Server Explorer a bit but it seems overly difficult to use for simple tasks such as "upload this file to server".  Is there a good solution out there?  Or do people just generally not do web development in Eclipse?  RSE seems great if I want to work directly on the server, but what about publishing on MY schedule?

I've been quite happy with Aptana Studio 2 in the past as it offers everything I need, but it's getting out-of-date and Studio 3 offers a whole new set of problems.  Maybe I just need a good, straightforward RSE tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on 2 things; what platform you're developing on and the nature of the target server.   If you're targeting a live server I'd say always upload manually (unless you're part of a live team), otherwise you could consider a more automatic solution.  I use Linux, so I've used rsync and sshfs before, both work well but have their own quirks.

HTH.

Comment: Developing on Ubuntu. Trying to find a solution that doesn't involve writing ant scripts, or running some sort of external application (like rsync or gFtp or whatever)  I want two mouse-clicks, max.  Target server could be any ftp/sftp supporting system.  I may or may not have access to connect via rsync.

Comment: On Ubuntu - have you tried the standard "Connect to server" that you access via the "Places" menu?  There's an SSH option which might work if you've already got SFTP, otherwise the FTP one works well for me.  The interface will be drag & drop.

Comment: Hi Robin, yes that does work, however I was hoping for a solution bundled with (or a plugin for) Eclipse.  I'm coming from a Dreamweaver background... maybe I was just spoiled, hoping for a "one app does everything" sort of solution.  Aptana 2.0 was REALLY good for that stuff, but seems to have compatibility issues with the latest Ubuntu.  The little testing I've done with Aptana 3.0 has left me very disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

At work I use http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/examples.html but it`s for more local/intranet situations (aslo rsync could help here).

And at home I use non-eclipse http://www.cyberkiko.com/page/FTPSync.aspx connected as favorite

But RSE also a good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand the reverse solution : 
Use a remote server, which stock your application.
Sync your local by mount your remote server via SSHFS.

For SSHFS you can do a Linux command like sshfs  .

- Good : Run without any Eclipse plugin and on all your computers…
- Bad  : Need desactivate the Eclipse DLTK auto indexer.

Or you can install the Eclipse Plugin «Remote System Explorer» which run SSHFS and do the same stuff.

- Good : You have an interface…
- Bad  :

  - […] Which is more complicated than the only one command that you need :p (SSHFS)…
  - You are now in a specific Eclipse configuration.
  - The plugin isn't available with some version of Eclipse.